# Как отменить данное действие на Iphone?

Tags: ios, вёрстка

как известно если доскролить страницу до конца, на обычных устройств дальше докручивать нельзя. На айфонах же можно крутить еще, и идет анимация как она возврощается на место. Скажите пожалуйста возможно ли отменить данное действие что бы если пользователь доскролил до конца не смог дальше скроллить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется bounce и его можно выключить, например через сториборд выключите у ScrollView эти галочки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на самом деле по UX iOS это делать не советуется, т.к. это позволяет пользователю мягко дать понять, что он дошел до конца, при этом взаимодействие остается плавным.

Comment: Я так понимаю это вы про настройки со стороны пользователя

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa т.е. со стороны пользователя? Это вы для своей таблицы/скролла можете выключить через сториборд/ксиб, либо же изменить эти же параметры через код